# phplibsec - loop login until connected

Tags: php, phpseclib

I would like to continue trying to connect to a remote server using the phplibsec package until the connection = true ... there is a standard code for what to do if it doesn't connect, but I rather check it over and over until it connects. I initially tried this code snippet below where if it gets to 5 attempts, it stops and says too many, but it just keeps not connecting. However, when I attempt to connect to it (in one line) and send a command, it works just fine.

```
$attempts = 0;
while (true) {
    if (!$sftp->login('user', 'pass')) {
        echo "unable to connect." . PHP_EOL;
        $attempt += 1;
        echo "Attempts: ".$attempts;
        continue;
    } else if ($attempts = 5) {
        echo "5 attempts, check user/password/ip";
        break;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($attempts = 5) {` should be `if ($attempts == 5) {` - not sure if that is the only problem as I haven't really looked closely

Comment: This is why you should put "constants" on the left like `if (5 = $attempts)`   which will throw an error when you mess it up.  `<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '='` see [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68df8b5a5c1bef57883cbc62ffebfcb2090ebbc2).  The other way it just sets `$attempts` to `5`  When it evaluates the condition which is always true.  So even if you login it says you hit your 5 attempts.